# Show Activity Indicator on viewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiactivityindicatorview

On `viewWillDisappear` I need to update quite a few `Core Data` records and in doing so it creates a lag when I move from one viewController to another (via Tab View Controller.)

In my `viewWillDisappear` method I call `settingsChanged()`, which looks like this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    //other things
    if anySettingChanged {
      settingsChanged()
    }
}

func settingsChanged() {
  // attempt to display activity indicator view
  context.performBlockAndWait { // on private queue
    // update a lot of Core Data records
    // attempt to hide activity indicator view
  }
}
```

**However, I can't update the view disappearing despite that view being visible during the lag. I just want to somehow show something is going on rather than a lag for 2-3 seconds.**  But I can't seem to display an activity indicator view! (I use the main thread to update the view!)

Using:

```
context.performBlock
```

solves the lag issue but causes errors in that my next viewControllers depend on Core Data having finished its updates. Specifically I get

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: '*** Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x12824cde0> was mutated while
>   being enumerated.'"

Comment: if you want method on viewWillDisappear then call in viewWillDisappear . but above you are calling in func viewDidDisappear. func viewDidDisappear is called when view controller completely disappears. So call in viewWillDisappear.

Comment: Fixed that, that was a mistake, viewWill is in my code.

Comment: For solving the crash you can implement local notification. Post a local notification when `context.performBlockAndWait` is finished, and perform fetch for the next VC only after the notification is posted.

Comment: @anders32 : Is context local variable in your class or it is in appdelegate or someother singleton class ??? If its local variable after viewwillDisappear the variable will be set to nil so you cant use performBlock you will have to use performBlockAndWait but you can improve user experience

Comment: It doesn't crash with performBlockAndWait - it lags. It crashes with performBlock. That may work with performBlock, but I'd highly prefer just using an activity view indicator until Core Data is finished.

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari interesting, the context is an instance variable in that View Controller that pulls from a Core Data class. It works sometimes though, with performBlock - crashing every once in awhile.

Comment: It seems that updating your core data records causes a crash – which is unrelated to your original problem or might mask it. Check if you or something you cause is changing an NSSet collection while it is being enumerated. Check that no one else is accessing it during the operation.

Comment: @anders32 : Do a simple task call performBlockAndWait in first statement start MBProgressHUD with statement like handling local data base or anything which makes sense for you and after context.save() remove the MBProgressHUD and pop your self :) Simple

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari - the problem is I can't seem to change the soon to be disappearing view!

Answer (score 0):

What do you do here it's to override the `viewWillDisappear` method, so you call too early the super references, try this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    //other things
    if anySettingChanged {
      settingsChanged()
    }
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't change the view. I'm trying to startAnimating my activity indicator which doesn't happen until I leave the view and then come back to it.